# Collect terms in a sum

Tags: summation, index

Suppose I have this expression

```
    Sum[F[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, 1, 3}]


(* F[i, 1] KroneckerDelta[1, k] + F[i, 2] KroneckerDelta[2, k] +
            F[i, 3] KroneckerDelta[3, k] *)
```

Is it possible for *Mathematica* to present the contracted result

```
F[i,k]
```

?

Comment: note this is only true for `i,k` integers in {1,2,3}.  That said even with appropriate assumptions it doesn't simplify as you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

While doing the `Sum` over `j`, you turn the second argument of `F` into a number. This concrete substitution has to be avoided.

To do this, we have to tell *Mathematica* that `F[i,j]` with a concrete number for `j` should be rewritten immediately as an expression that can be simplified to something involving `F[i,k]`. To do this, I add the following symbolic rule for `F`:

```
Clear[i, j, k];
F[i_, j_?NumericQ] := F[i, k] KroneckerDelta[k, j]

Assuming[k > 0 && k ∈ Integers && k < 4,
 Simplify[Sum[F[i, j] KroneckerDelta[j, k], {j, 1, 3}]
  ]
 ]

(* ==> F[i, k] *)
```

Comment: interesting but it seems not all that useful in general since you can only handle the one specific symbol k that way.

Comment: @george2079 Well, that's what the question is about.