# Symbolic evaluation of the sum of KroneckerDelta

Tags: symbolic, summation

I want to evaluate this simple expression
$$
\sum_n f(n)\delta_{mn} = f(m)
$$
using this:

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, Infinity}]
```

However Mathematica didn't reduce this expression. Could someone tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51424/collect-terms-in-a-sum

Comment: In my opinion this should be tagged as a bug because it's a regression. In version 9, the sum works with any finite numerical upper limit, but not with `Infinity`. But in version 8, the simplification works even when the upper limit is `Infinity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The following solution works in *Mathemtica* 8.0.4, but not in 9.0.1:

This requires an assumption about the parameter `m`:

```
Assuming[m > 0 && m ∈ Integers, 
 Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, Infinity}]]

(* ==> f[m] *)
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but mathematica didn't reduce the expression neither. I am using Mathematica 9.

Comment: @entron You're right, it works in version 8 and not in version 9! I'll think about it. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Does this work in 8?  `Assuming[m > 0 && m ∈ Integers && nn > m, 
 Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, nn}]] `

Comment: @george2079 yes - that works fine. It's the infinite case that causes trouble.

Comment: that then suggests another approach to the linked question